# Array and swap function

Tags: actionscript-3

Here is a simple drag and drop "game". I have 4 dragged movieClips (paris, london etc) and 4 dropped movieClips where you need to put dragged object (paris_match, london_match etc).

1) So, how to create correct Array with dropped movieClips?
2) How to swap dragged objects between themselves when they are on dropped places?

Big thanks.

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.geom.Point;

public class Travelling extends MovieClip 
{
    protected var originalPosition:Point;
            protected var hitArray:Array; // EDIT

    public function Travelling() 
    {
        originalPosition = new Point(x, y); 
hitArray = new Array("paris_match" , "berlin_match" , "rome_match" ,  "london_match"); // Edit
        buttonMode = true;
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, down);
    }
    protected function down(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        parent.addChild(this);
        startDrag();
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stageUp);
    }
    protected function stageUp(e:Event):void
    {
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stageUp);
        stopDrag();
        if(dropTarget) {
               for (var i = 0; i < hitArray.length; i++) { // Edit

            // !!!!!------This Array works not correctly-----!!!!!
            if (dropTarget.parent.name == hitArray[i]) { // Edit

                x = dropTarget.parent.x;
                y = dropTarget.parent.y;

            } else {
            returnToOriginalPosition();
            }
            } // EDIT
        } else {
            returnToOriginalPosition();
        }
    }
    protected function returnToOriginalPosition():void
    {
        x = originalPosition.x;
        y = originalPosition.y;
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried any approaches yet or do you want us to come up with it for you? If it's the former, please show us.

Comment: I made an Array. But it works not correctly. Works just with last name in Array. All dropped objects I can put only on "london_match" (I think that Array's index "i" after running program always is equal 3). See "Edit" in program comments. And I have no idea how to make swap function ((

Comment: There are some questions your code raises.  What is `dropTarget` and how is it getting set?  What `addChild()` operation occurs to make it the child of `Travelling`.  After reading your code, I'm still at a loss to comprehend what you mean by a "swap function", especially since that seems a tangential issue to the code you've written.  Regardless, if what you need is an array swapping function, see here: http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?342500-Array-swap%28a-b%29-method

Comment: dropTarget : DisplayObject
[read-only] Specifies the display object over which the sprite is being dragged, or on which the sprite was dropped. "parent.addChild(this);" do the same as "this.setChildIndex("instance name", this.numChildren - 1);". Dragged object gets the highest index and goes to the front. "swap function" I mean to swap dragged objects between themselves when they are on dropped places. - http://www.primarygames.com/science/farmanimals/games/cowdragdrop/ like in this game. I saw your link, maybe I should to create another Array with dragged objects!?